# ASP .NET model within itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Can I have model class within itself? It seems it works but every time I tried to retrive the document in controller the `SimilarDocuments` field was always `null` then after googling I found a work around instead of `Document document = db.Documents.Find(id)`I use `Document document = db.Documents.Include("SimilarDocuments").FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id)` but something tells me its not a ideal way how to approach this problem. Why simple `.Find(id)`didnt work?

Here is simplified version of my model:

```
public class Document
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> SimilarDocuments { get; set; }

    public Document()
    {
        SimilarDocuments = new List<Document>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can switch to lazy-loading by using `virtual ICollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the NavigationProperty to be lazy-loaded. This will not happen automatically, if you do not mark the `ICollection<EntityType>` as `virtual`.

When you change that and make it virtual (and you do not explicitly deactivate lazy-loading somewhere else in code), it will load the data on demand - as long as your `DBContext` is opened.

```
public class Document {
  public virtual ICollection<Document> SimilarDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

Here you can read more about the topic of lazy-loading and eager-loading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score 0):

because when Find methos is invoked from **db.Documents** it search in every **Document element**. your serach aim to search inside a field for each document and that is why you should use *Include("SimilarDocuments")*

- Documents

  - Document -> **this is where db.Documents.Find search**

    - SimilarDocuments --> you want to search here

Comment: I dont want to search inside Document I want to retrieve it by its ID and then Im naively expecting it would have every field with it. So am I understanding it correctly if I would have lots of collections inside my model I would have to include each and every one of them?